# 3D game demo in XNA

Tags: xna, 3d, xna-4.0

Does anyone know of a decent 3D game tutorial with source code?

I'm really new with 3D development for XNA and have found that the best way to figure out how to code for something is to look at pre-existing source code and figure out what goes where.

Comment: Your question is valid, but not for this site. Since there's no correct answer to "where to get started", those questions are not constructive for the site. See the [FAQ] about where to get started and some other sites that are a better fit for these types of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the official XNA samples: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/

Answer (score -2):

xna is dead and no longer supported. i suggest getting started with unity, friendlier for a starter and a more complete solution than xna.

Comment: MonoGame is not dead, so thus XNA is not dead.